# PHP using different libxml2 version, than the one installed in /usr/lib/

Tags: php

I tried to install Mediawiki, which told me to update my libxml2 to at least version 2.7.3.
So I've checked that and found `/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6` to be installed. `xml2-config --version` also returns `2.7.6`. But when reading the outputs of `phpinfo();` it tells me the `libXML Compiled Version` is `2.6.32`.

How can I tell PHP to use the correct libxml2, while avoiding recompiling anything by hand, as I like to use the Ubuntu package-upgrades in the future.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.04.3 (lucid) LTS and having installed the PHP5 and libapache-mod-php5 packages from the main sources (`PHP 5.3.5-0.dotdeb.0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP 5.3.5-0.dotdeb.0` indicates that the php packages that you have installed are from dotdeb.org, rather than the main archive. These packages are **not** compiled for Ubuntu, but for Debian, and it's likely that these were built against an older version of libxml2.

You would be better off using the php5 packages from Ubuntu, or if a more recent version is needed, to use packages from a trusted PPA.